# When setting UIWebView.scrollView.contentInset the webview's innerheight will change to zero

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I want to add a footerView to `UIWebView`, so I have set `UIWebView.scrollView.contentSize`,but it will bring many questions.
I print webview innerHeight, it changes to 0. This is main reason.
Is there anyone who has the same question? And how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show codes?

Comment: self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.height, 0);
when call the code. webview innerHeight will equal 0.
can call NSLog(@"print webview info : \n innerHeight %@", [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"innerHeight"]); to print